# What would be the language generated by Σ*-x?

Tags: formal-languages

Say, for example, Σ={x,y}.
And you carried out the operation Σ*-x. What would be the resulting language? Would it essentially be y* or would it just minus one occurrence of x in all strings generated in Σ*?
i.e xxyyxx  to xyyxx.

Comment: I wonder if someone voted this down because they didn't understand the question.

Comment: probably this question belongs in cs.stackexchange.com. It has to do with operations on some formal languages. In particular the question is what the resulting language is if you take the language of the symbols `x` and `y` under the `*` operation, and you subtract from it the string `x`. (at least, that's how I understood the question)

Comment: Yes that was the question, I forgot about that case. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the language of all strings generated by `Σ*` minus the string `x`. (so: xx, epsilon, xyx, y, etc... but not x)